# How to retrieve users using database-indexes

Tags: indexing, oracle10g, database-indexes

I'm on an Oracle 10 db, and I need to identify **which users** are using the index IDX001 (example).

I already saw about monitoring to identify if an index is being used. This was done successfully, but I would like to know if there's a way to identify which user made a query using that index.

The main purpose is to identify which app-user is using the index.

Also, I'm about to upgrade to Oracle 11. So I'm also considering features that may be only available on 11.